# How to debug Joomla Jquery Conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

Joomla site works fine everywhere else but only on native article's pages where it keeps stuck and hanged for hours.

here is the google chrome inspector errors

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'zIndex' of undefined$.fn.caroufredsel.$.fn.carouFredSel.y._cfs_bind_events.y.bind._onafter @ VM286:1(anonymous function) @ VM286:1m.speed.d.complete @ VM178:4m.Callbacks.j @ VM178:2m.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ VM178:2i @ VM178:4m.fx.tick @ VM178:4
VM294:2165 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined(anonymous function) @ VM294:2165
VM307:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_navigate' of undefinedcircleFlip @ VM307:20
VM294:2165 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined(anonymous function) @ VM294:2165
VM305:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'container' of undefinedg @ VM305:9(anonymous function) @ VM305:9m.extend.each @ VM178:2m.fn.m.each @ VM178:2u @ VM305:9(anonymous function) @ VM305:9m.extend.each @ VM178:2m.fn.m.each @ VM178:2e.fn.extend.revredraw @ VM305:9(anonymous function) @ VM305:9
19VM294:2165 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined(anonymous function) @ VM294:2165
VM934:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'zIndex' of undefined$.fn.caroufredsel.$.fn.carouFredSel.y._cfs_bind_events.y.bind._onafter @ VM934:1(anonymous function) @ VM934:1m.speed.d.complete @ VM906:4m.Callbacks.j @ VM906:2m.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ VM906:2i @ VM906:4m.fx.tick @ VM906:4
2VM294:2165 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined(anonymous function) @ VM294:2165
VM947:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_navigate' of undefinedcircleFlip @ VM947:20
8VM945:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'container' of undefinedg @ VM945:9(anonymous function) @ VM945:9m.extend.each @ VM906:2m.fn.m.each @ VM906:2u @ VM945:9(anonymous function) @ VM945:9m.extend.each @ VM906:2m.fn.m.each @ VM906:2e.fn.extend.revredraw @ VM945:9(anonymous function) @ VM945:9
2VM294:2165 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
```

here is the site link: http://oizix.com/version2/
and if you click on about us
the page stucks?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You appear to have some sort in infinite loop in your JS. Try disabling any modules on this page. Once you find which one it is, find an alternative module

Comment: All modules disabled and still its doing the same?

Comment: I can't appear to see now. The "About" menu item is showing a 404

Comment: http://oizix.com/version2/index.php/about-us
there you go
I have disabled almost everything on this page.

Comment: @Lodder i have found the conflicting plugin its called System - SEF which is for SEO and html tags if i enable it, the page stuck and hangs if not i get an error of Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <, you can load the page again and check for inspector errors.